# How to extract only specific columns from list of 100 columns

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am working with DB2 database and I have a table with almost 80 columns but I am concerned about only 3 columns that I need to read. How can I extract data only for these 3 columns? Is there a way that I don't have to create an entity class without all those 80 getters and setters? Please let me know if there is any alternate approach. Or is there is a way generate such entity classes automatically?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write native query and put it to `createSQLQuery()` method. Two options here, Suppose you have a query

```
SELECT t.COLUMN1, t.COLUMN2, t.COLUMN3 from TABLE t;
```

When you call directly `uniqueResult()` or `list()`, you will get `Object[]` or `List<Object[]>`respectively. Hibernate should determine correct types and you can cast array elements.

Or you can create an Entity with only these columns with coresponding names as DB table and call `createSQLQuery().addEntity(MyEntity.class)` and then work with this class.

For more information check [Hibernate Manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#querysql)

Comment: Thank you, Paul. I am going to try this and update if that works.